# List All Folders, Subfolders, and Files by name and path

Tags: sharepoint-online, subfolders

I am using python with the sharepy module to make requests to sharepoint. I would really like to know to get get all of the folders, subfolders, and files of a sharepoint site via a http request. I can list folders and files like so:

```
r = s.get(spo_site + """_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('""" + root_folder + """')/Folders""")
```

But it need it to go deep into the folder structure to get the relative urls and names of the files and folders. I would think this would be possible considering most sites have an export to excel button. The reason I want to do this with code because I need to go through a bunch of sites. Please Help.

**EDIT**
Mike Smith response answered my question. My code is like this:

```
r = s.get(spo_site + """_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef&$top=5000)
```

This works great but the limit is 5000 items. I am going to need much more than this. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CAML query may work. If multiple calls are ok then:

You can get a list of libraries using:

```
_api/web/lists?$filter=BaseTemplate eq 101
```

Note that 101 is for the Document Library template. A long list of template IDs here: https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2015/02/sharepoint-2013-list-and-library.html

And then from the list of libraries, get every folder/file using:

```
_api/Lists/getbyTitle('Documents')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,Id
```

Comment: Smith, Thank you mike this is working! One last question, how would you increase the number of items coming back? Right now I am only getting 100 back where I know have like 7,000 objects in my test directory. Thanks again!

Comment: Add `&$Top=5000`. For more than your List Threshold Limit you will need to use paging. For library paging you can use Skip and Top: `$Skip=10000&$Top=5000`. Skip does not work for lists. Use $skiptoken and a little code.   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#page-through-returned-items